# ESP8266-12F accelstepper wont boot

Tags: esp8266

If I use 9, 10, 7, 6 , 8, 11 pins for accelstepper, ESP8266 wont boot
If I use other pins, all good.

What is the problem?

I use accelstepper and Arduino latest versions.

sketch which won't boot -

```
    #include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <MultiStepper.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>

const char* ssid = "wiflya";
const char* password = ".........";

#define HALFSTEP 8   

// Определение пинов для управления двигателем
#define motorPin1  13 // IN1 на 1-м драйвере ULN2003
#define motorPin2  12 // IN2 на 1-м драйвере ULN2003
#define motorPin3  14 // IN3 на 1-м драйвере ULN2003
#define motorPin4  16 // IN4 на 1-м драйвере ULN2003


// Определение пинов для управления двигателем
#define motor2Pin1  6 // IN1 на 2-м драйвере ULN2003
#define motor2Pin2  3 // IN2 на 2-м драйвере ULN2003
#define motor2Pin3  5 // IN3 на 2-м драйвере ULN2003
#define motor2Pin4  4 // IN4 на 2-м драйвере ULN2003

// Инициализируемся с последовательностью выводов IN1-IN3-IN2-IN4 
// для использования AccelStepper с 28BYJ-48
AccelStepper stepper1(HALFSTEP, motorPin1, motorPin3, motorPin2, motorPin4);
AccelStepper stepper2(HALFSTEP, motor2Pin1, motor2Pin3, motor2Pin2, motor2Pin4);

void setup() {
  //Serial.begin(115200);
  //Serial.println("Booting");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    //Serial.println("Connection Failed! Rebooting...");
    delay(5000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  stepper1.setMaxSpeed(1300.0);
  stepper1.setAcceleration(400.0);
  stepper1.setSpeed(1300.0);

  stepper2.setMaxSpeed(1300.0);
  stepper2.setAcceleration(400.0);
  stepper2.setSpeed(1300.0);

  //stepper1.moveTo(20000);

  // Port defaults to 8266
  // ArduinoOTA.setPort(8266);

  // Hostname defaults to esp8266-[ChipID]
  // ArduinoOTA.setHostname("myesp8266");

  // No authentication by default
  // ArduinoOTA.setPassword("admin");

  // Password can be set with it's md5 value as well
  // MD5(admin) = 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
  // ArduinoOTA.setPasswordHash("21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3");

  ArduinoOTA.begin();
}

void loop() {
    // Изменяем направление, если шаговик достигает заданного положения
  //if(stepper1.distanceToGo()==0)
  //  stepper1.moveTo(-stepper1.currentPosition());
  stepper2.runSpeed();
  stepper1.runSpeed();
  //stepper2.runSpeed();


  ArduinoOTA.handle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pins 6 to 11 of the esp8266 are QIO SPI pins connected to flash memory of the esp8266. You can't use them.

Comment: Thank. I'm finding more info about this. can't use 6-11 pins, cant use gpio1 - if i'm connect to uln2003 - esp wont boot.. cant use gpio0 - wont boot if i'm connect to uln2003.   And what we have - only 3,5,4,12,13,14,16 i'm can use (with uln2003) and cant connect two bipolar motor - so very bad.

Comment: this is for NodeMcu, but it applies https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402066/esp8266-free-gpios-for-relay-switching/404845#404845

Comment: or here https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap04%20-%20Microcontroller.html